# Prevent guest users from writing to Cloud Firestore database in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have an instagram-like app. I want to implement guest users authentication, so the people don't have to register to see the other people photos.

But I also need to disable all writing to the database functionality for guest users. How can I achieve this?

Let's say I have this default security rules:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I should not do it in real life. Just for the example.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: post your structure please

Comment: My db is actually clean by now. I just wonder how do I **disable all writing functionality for guest users**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is pretty much directly addressed [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication), but it would look something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches the 'author_id' field
    // of the document
    match /photos/{photoId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow any authenticated user to create a photo so long as the `uid` field matches their own authenticated `uid`, but will allow anyone (signed in or not) to read the data in the `photos` collection.